# How to change existing .apk application id?

Tags: android, apk

I have existing .apk file and need to change applicationId.

I know how to change application id in `build.gradle`, but not sure how to change application id of existing (already built) .apk file (not java package names).

Is it possible?

Comment: use "Refactor" option on your Package Name from Project Tab.

Comment: That does not answer the question how to change the name inside the already built APK.

Comment: decompile APK, change package, build again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to rename the package name then there exists some projects on github that will let you rename the package of a given APK. I have tested it myself and it worked on most of my APKs but not on all. You can give it at least a try:

https://github.com/testwhat/PackageRenamer

https://github.com/sjitech/ApkRename (my recommendation)

Please not that it might not be legal to modify APKs you don't are the owner off! And you will also have to sign the app after you have changed it but this could be done using an own key e.g. a debug key.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Tried this one and it didn't work: https://github.com/sjitech/ApkRename applicationid changed, but when I am trying to install it fails installation

Comment: Yeah thats the issue. It does not work easily with all applications. What error message do you receive?

Comment: Application did not install.

Comment: But, after signing it with key it installed with changed package name! But crashes after launch.

Comment: Ok I think you won't be able to use those package renamers using your APK. Package renaming is a quite complex process and your APK seems to be not compatible to those renamers. An other option would be editing the package manually, there exist some instructions but I am not sure whether it would be worth it.

Comment: It crashes giving specific error with failing to initialize content providers. It seems like java package names changed. I need to change only application id, will spend more time.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider `my.new.package.name.model.sqlite.provider` for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority